# Algebraic proof for the identity $\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{m-k}{{n \choose {k}}}= {{n-1}\choose m}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

I can't figure out an algebraic proof for the following identity, (and I don't know if I can use the binomial theorem for this one):
$$\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{m-k}{{n \choose {k}}}= {{n-1}\choose m}$$

Thank you, for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried writing $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan who knows :/ I posted an answer over 30 minutes ago and haven't received a word from the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$(-1)^{m-k}=\binom{-1}{m-k},$$ so you want to prove
$$\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{-1}{m-k}{\binom{n}{k}}= {\binom{n-1}{m}}.$$ But that's just a special case of the Vandermonde identity.

Using generating functions, the identity follows from the evaluation of the coefficient at $x^m$ on both sides of the identity $$\frac{1}{1+x}\cdot(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

We desire to prove, by induction, that
$$\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^{k} {n \choose k} = (-1)^m{n-1 \choose m}$$
We start with the case $m=0$
$$\sum_{k=0}^0 (-1)^{k} {n \choose k} = {n \choose 0}= {n-1 \choose 0}$$
We now apply induction. We first assume that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^{k} {n \choose k} = (-1)^{m-1}{n-1 \choose m-1} \tag{1}$$
And now we begin the induction
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m} (-1)^{k} {n \choose k}$$
$$=(-1)^{m}{n \choose m}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^{k} {n \choose k}$$
$$=(-1)^{m}{n \choose m}+(-1)^{m-1}{n-1 \choose m-1}$$
$$=(-1)^{m}\left[{n \choose m}-{n-1 \choose m-1}\right]$$
We now have to apply the identity $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and we are done.

Comment: It seems that your claim leads to $$\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^{k-m} {n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose m}$$ different to OP's question $$\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^{m-k} {n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose m}$$

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Note that $(-1)^{k-m} = (-1)^{-(m-k)} = (-1)^{m-k}$. The two are not different

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan This comes down to the fact that $(-1)^k = \frac{1}{(-1)^k}$

Comment: --)Nice trick. I did not see that. Thank you. One up vote from me.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n-1}m x^m
$$
but also
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{n-1} =(1+x)^n \frac1{1+x} & = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(-1)^lx^l \\
& =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^{m-k}\binom{n}k \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
now compare the coefficients of $m$ in the two expansions. although (2) is formally an infinite sum, you can see that for $m \gt n-1$ the terms are zero

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{m-k}\binom nk
&=(-1)^m\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k\left[\binom {n-1}{k-1}+\binom {n-1}k\right]
&&\text{as $(-1)^{-k}=(-1)^k$}\\
&=(-1)^m\bigg\lbrace \cancel1-\left[\cancel{\binom {n-1}0}+\bcancel{\binom {n-1}1}\right]\\
&\qquad\quad\quad\quad+\left[\bcancel{\binom {n-1}1}+\cancel{\binom {n-1}2}\right]\\
&\qquad\quad\quad\quad-\left[\cancel{\binom {n-1}2}+\bcancel{\binom {n-1}3}\right]\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\cdots\\
&\qquad\;\;+(-1)^m\left[\bcancel{\binom {n-1}{m-1}}+\binom {n-1}m\right]\bigg\rbrace\\
&=\binom {n-1}m\end{align}$$